# Sending relative data from mapped array into a modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-modal, react-slick

[image: Demonstration of what should happen]

So I have mapped data from array into a carousel, creating total of twenty carousel items. Each element has "same" button embedded into them. I want to send the relative data from each element into the modal when that button is clicked and honestly I have no idea even where to start from.

This is the code I have currently for this component:

Edit: highlighted the data I would like to pass into the relative modal.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import Slider from 'react-slick';
    import Modal from 'react-modal';

    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

    import { fetchActionM } from '../../store/actions/moviepageActions';

    const img_url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original';

    const customStyles = {
        content : {
          top                   : '50%',
          left                  : '50%',
          right                 : 'auto',
          bottom                : 'auto',
          marginRight           : '-50%',
          transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
          color                 : 'white',
          background: '#080a0a none repeat scroll 0% 0%',
          width: '600px',
        }
    };

    Modal.setAppElement('#root')

    class ActionMov extends React.Component{
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
                modalIsOpen: false
            };

            this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
            this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
            this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);


        }

        openModal() {
            this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
        }

        afterOpenModal(){
            this.subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
        }

        closeModal(){
            this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
        }

        render(){
        //send same mapped data from this into the modal when clicked on the button <FontAwesomeIcon onClick....
        let action;
        if(this.props.action.length > 0){
            action = this.props.action[0].results.map(ac => (
                <div className='sliderbox' key={ac.id}>
                    <div className='text-block'>
                        <h5 className='sliderTitle'>{ac.title}</h5>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => this.openModal({ac})} icon="plus-circle" className='sliderIcon' />

{/* I need same data from these two be passed into the relative modal */}

                        <p className='sliderRelease'>{ac.release_date}</p>
                        <p className='sliderVote'>{ac.vote_average}</p>

{/* Just highlighting this area */}

                    </div>
                    <img className='sliderImg' src={`${img_url}${ac.poster_path}`} alt={ac.title} />
                </div>
            ));
        }

        const settings = {
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 6,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            draggable: true,
        };
            return (
                <div>
                    <Slider {...settings}>
                        {action}
                    </Slider>
                    <Modal
                    isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                    onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                    onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                    style={customStyles}
                    contentLabel='Movies modal'
                    >
                    {
                        //Would like to print relative data here
                    }
                    <h2 ref={subtitle => this.subtitle = subtitle}>TITLE GOES HERE</h2>
                        <div>
                        <p>Id: {`<id goes here>`}</p>
                        <h5 className='modalRelease'>Released: {`<release date goes here>`}</h5>
                        <h5 className='modalVote'>Rating: {`<rating goes here>`}</h5>
                        </div>
                    <button className='modalClose' onClick={this.closeModal}>X</button>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            action: state.movies.actions
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ActionMov);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of the button you can set it to the state and can access inside the modal.
First let's `initialize` it inside the `constructor`

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            modalIsOpen: false,
            movie: {
               id: '', release: '', rating: ''
        }
    };

    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);


}
```

Now lets set it up on `onClick` event, you are actually passing the object to `openModal` method

```
openModal(movie) {
        this.setState({
           modalIsOpen: true,
           movie: movie
        }); 
}
```

Now you are good to access it inside the modal

```
<Modal
    isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
    onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
    onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
    style={customStyles}
    contentLabel='Movies modal'
>
    {
        //Would like to print relative data here
    }
    <h2 ref={subtitle => this.subtitle = subtitle}>TITLE GOES HERE</h2>
    <div>
        <p>Id: {this.state.movie.id}</p>
        <h5 className='modalRelease'>Released: {this.state.movie.release}</h5>
        <h5 className='modalVote'>Rating: {this.state.movie.rating}</h5>
    </div>
    <button className='modalClose' onClick={this.closeModal}>X</button>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not sure if this is actually passing the data I want from carousel (mapped array) into the modal, it seem that it passes empty strings instead of the actual data I need.

Comment: `onClick={() => this.openModal(ac)}` can you please try this(removed curly braces{ac}), If I understood you correctly you need to pass the data of the movie/item you have clicked? Also can you please `console.log(movie)` in `openModal()`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, it works just like I wanted it to work! You are awesome!